# How to convert some items in a tuple from list to float?

Tags: python, list, tuples

Due to some slicing I did previously in my script I ended up with a huge tuple that looks like this:

```
(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, [102.37], [129.6], [190.64], [181.98], [192.79])
```

In the example above the first 7 items are floats and the other are lists containing one element each, which are also floats.

I would like to get rid of the lists and keep floats so I can add up all the values to calculate the average stock price by 6 month period.

What is the most pythonic way to achieve this?

Comment: do you want to end up with a tuple again? or do you want a list?

Comment: I want to keep the tuple.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This function returns a float whether it is given a float or a list:

```
def delistify(x):
    try:
        return x[0]
    except TypeError:
        return x
```

If you need the output to be a tuple, you can use it like:

```
print tuple( delistify(x) for x in my_list )
```

Or, if a list is also ok, the most pythonic is a list comprehension:

```
print [ delistify(x) for x in my_list ]
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to extract the numbers from the lists:

```
In [1]: t = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, [102.37], [129.6], [190.64], [181.98], [192.79])
In [2]: tuple(tt if isinstance(tt, float) else tt[0] for tt in t)
Out[2]: (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 102.37, 129.6, 190.64, 181.98, 192.79)
```

If you want to "get rid of" the lists:

```
In [3]: tuple(tt for tt in t if isinstance(tt, float))
Out[3]: (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

Comment: Type checking using the `type` function is not reliable. You should be using `isinstance` instead.

Comment: @ScottHunter yup --apparently OP wants to extract the numbers from the lists.